# IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status (Google Maps)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, xcode-storyboard

From few days, I'm experiencing following issue:

```
Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for SomeViewController (BeW-27-X9H): dlopen(GoogleMaps.framework, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    GoogleMaps.framework: mach-o, but wrong filetype
```

I have 28 errors like this in different view controllers, even though I only use Google Maps in few of them. Because of this issue, I cannot edit some of view controllers (they are often blank). I can edit other controllers, but often then don't update themselves (I change something and cannot see it), unless I re-open storyboard or restart Xcode.

I've read countless solutions, but none of them is working. I've read that the cause is cocoa pods, however I cannot downgrade to 1.4, because some of my pods require 1.5. post_install fixes also don't help.

I've tried cleaning build folder & derived data.
I've tried re-running pod update.
I've tried restarting XCode and Mac OS multiple times.

Still, issue persists. One time, for no reason, it disappeared for several minutes and I could easily edit storyboard. Then it came back.

If it's really an issue with cocoa pods, I've tried manual integration, without cocoa pods. Still, there's the same error.

I've also tried the following solution:

```
import GoogleMaps

class GoogleMapView: GMSMapView {

}
```

But the issue won't disappear. Is there anything it can be done to fix this annoying issue? It appeared out of nowhere.

Comment: Does the app open on a device/simulator without crashing?

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Currently experienced this issue, I noticed some changes were being made automatically by xcode everytime I open the storyboard and I always add to revert then for the views to render appropriately but now I can't get them to show anymore...were you able to solve this yet, and how if you did? @Makalele

Comment: Well, it just vanished one day by itself, was working fine for something like a month, few days ago it reappeared and today it vanished after I installed mac os update (maybe reboot helped, hard to say). It is extremely annoying issue as there's no good method to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is superstupid, but sometimes I just delete **@IBDesignable** view from storyboard then undo.

Comment: I've tried that, didn't work. I even have this silly error in view controllers that don't have GMSMapView at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a custom view contains GMSMapView(not sub class), 
and use the custom view in Storyboard instead.

Comment: Even if I change GMSMapView subclass to UIView errors won't go away. They look like they're "cached".

Answer (score 0):

I have encontre some rendering issues (with other components) on storyboard files. I haven't understood the main reason, but i think that it's related to hardware performance (not sure). 
The workaround is to momentary change the class of the view causing the problem (use standard UIView) to easily edit storyboard, and undo this change after finishing updates.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is I'd have to do this in all controllers, because even one left causes the whole storyboard to break. Even more.. I also got errors when editing xib files and I don't have Google Maps in any of them. This issue appeared out of nowhere...

Comment: I even tried changing class GoogleMapView: GMSMapView to class GoogleMapView: UIView, but errors won't go away.

Comment: Can you share a sample storyboard causing the problem, i will try to check on my own machine and get back to you with a feedback.

Comment: It's not an easy task. I have so many controllers that it's just too time consuming. And I cannot share a whole project. Anyway, I've created an empty project, added map to it and it works just fine. I guess it's some conflict between map and other UI components. But there are just too many to figure it out.